# How to write a sql query returns list of orders which can be fulfilled with given items

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new at SQL and I need to write a query which returns list of orders that can be fulfilled with the items in the inventory.

Lets say the following table shows orders and required items to get them fulfilled.

```
------------------------------
| OrderID | Required Item No |
------------------------------
| ORD001  |         Item007  |
| ORD001  |         Item008  |
| ORD001  |         Item009  |
| ORD002  |         Item008  |
| ORD002  |         Item009  |
| ORD002  |         Item012  |
| ORD003  |         Item008  |
| ORD003  |         Item014  |
```

So In order to get fulfilled,

- ORD001 needs  Item007,Item008,Item009
- ORD002 needs  Item008,Item009,Item012
- ORD003 needs  Item008,Item014

And Lets assume this table is show my inventory

```
--------------------------
| Item Unique Id |Item No |
--------------------------
| 001            | Item007|
| 002            | Item008|
| 003            | Item008|
| 004            | Item012|
| 005            | Item009|
| 006            | Item014|
| 007            | Item015|
```

In this case, the query should returns ORD001 and ORD003. Can somebody help me on this?

**My first attempt**

Following query returns my inventory

```
SELECT ItemNo, COUNT(ItemNo) AS QTY 
FROM InventoryTable 
GROUP BY ItemNo

------------------------------
| ItemNo |        QTY        |
------------------------------
| Item007|         1         |
| Item008|         2         |
| Item009|         1         |
| Item012|         1         |
| Item014|         1         | 
| Item015|         1         |
```

This query returns list of required item for a spesific order

```
SELECT ItemNo, COUNT(ItemNo) AS QTY 
FROM OrdersTable 
Where OrderID ='ORD003' 
Group By ReqItemNo

------------------------------
| ItemNo  |        QTY        |
------------------------------
| Item008 |         1         |
| Item0014|         1         |
```

I could not find a way to subtract item quantities between these two tables and make the subtraction for each order and return available orders.

**Thanks to @Gordon Linoff for his suggestion**

```
select t1.OrderID
from t1 
left join inventory i
    on t.required_item_no = i.item_no
group by t1.OrderId
having count(*) = count(i.item_no)
```

This query seems correct but it returns ORD001,ORD002,ORD003 for the example above. When the Item009 is assigned to ORD001, because there will be no Item009 anymore, the query should not fulfill ORD002.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want the order where the required items for an order are in inventory. This will provide that list, but it ignores other order requirements. IOW, if the first order depletes an item required for the 2nd order, it won't pick up on that.

```
SELECT 
    t1.OrderID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t1.required_item_no) as `required_items`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT i.item_no) as `items_on_hand`
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN inventory i
    ON t1.required_item_no = i.item_no
GROUP BY t1.OrderId
HAVING `required_items` = `items_on_hand`;
```

**UPDATE**

I see that the query above fails to consider the quantity of each inventory item, and would include items that exist with a zero quantity. The following update should address this issue.

Because of the way order items and inventory are stored, instead of directly referencing the tables, I've used a sub-select in the following. Performance will be an issue when a large number of items are added to the table. You may want to reconsider how the quantities are stored and have one row per inventory item with a column to store the quantity on hand. Same for the order table.

```
SELECT 
    t1.OrderID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t1.required_item_no) as `required_items`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT i.item_no) as `items_on_hand`
FROM (
        SELECT 
            OrderID,
            required_item_no,
            COUNT(*) as `QTY`
        FROM OrdersTable
        GROUP BY OrderID, required_item_no
        ) t1 

LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                item_no,
                COUNT(*) as `QTY`
            FROM inventory
            GROUP BY item_no
        ) i
    ON t1.required_item_no = i.item_no AND 
    i.QTY >= t1.QTY
GROUP BY t1.OrderId
HAVING `required_items` = `items_on_hand`;
```

Comment: thank you for your respond. since I could not use newly declared variable name, edited the query and test it.
SELECT 
    t1.OrderID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t1.required_item_no) as required_items,
    COUNT(DISTINCT inventory.item_no) as items_on_hand
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN inventory i
    ON t1.required_item_no = i.item_no
GROUP BY t1.OrderId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.required_item_no) = COUNT(DISTINCT inventory.item_no);
But it still gives me the same result with Gordon Linoff's respond. In my test db, I only added one item into inventory. But it returned more then one order. am i doing wrng

Comment: What "newly declared variable name" are you talking about? There aren't any variable names in my answer.

Comment: What did I mean with that the query gave an error when I used this line (`required_items` = `items_on_hand`). I instead used this (t1.OrderId HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.required_item_no) = COUNT(DISTINCT inventory.item_no))

Comment: I'm afraid that the update won't work either. This is because of the way the order items and inventory are being stored. Instead on one row per inventory item with the quantity on hand, you have a row for each item in inventory. Same for the order items. Unusual way to store this info. For the query to work, it would need to use a sub-select instead of the table references.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Thrasher, I appreciate your afford. I will try your suggestions